# How do I stop MacOS updates from overwriting my auto_master file?

Tags: macos, updates, nfs

How do I stop MacOS updates from overwriting my auto_master file?
Every non-trivial MacOS update always removes my custom auto_master and puts in the default auto_master. I actually only add a single line to the end of the file and do not even modify the existing lines because they are irrelevant for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have spent quite a bit of time figuring out automounts of NFS shares in OS X...

Somewhere along the line, Apple decided allowing mounts directly into /Volumes should not be possible:

/etc/auto_master **(see last line)**:

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
/-          auto_nfs    -nobrowse,nosuid
```

/etc/auto_nfs **(this is all one line)**:

```
/Volumes/my_mount    -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc nfs://192.168.1.1:/exports/my_share
```

Make sure you:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/auto_nfs
```

Otherwise the automounter will not be able to read the config and fail with a  `... parse_entry: getmapent for map failed...` error in `/var/log/messages`

This will not work (anymore!) though it "should".

```
$ sudo automount -cv
...
automount: /Volumes/my_mount: mountpoint unavailable
```

**Note that, if you manually create the mount point using `mkdir`, it will mount.
But, upon restart, OS X removes the mount point, and automounting will fail.**

### What's the solution?

It's so easy my jaw dropped when I figured it out.
Basically, we are tricking OS X into thinking we're mounting **somewhere else.**

When you're talking about paths in just about any environment, the root folder is the highest path you can reach, whether it's `C:\` (windows) or `/` (*nix)

When you're at this path, attempting to reach the parent path, via `..` will keep you at the root path.

For example: `/../../../../` is still just `/`

By now, a few of you have already figured it out.

### TL;DR / Solution:

Change your `/etc/auto_nfs` config from **(this is all one line)**:

```
/Volumes/my_mount    -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc nfs://192.168.1.1:/exports/my_share
```

For pre-Catalina: To **(this is all one line)**

```
/../Volumes/my_mount    -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc nfs://192.168.1.1:/exports/my_share
```

For Catalina and up: To **(this is all one line)**

```
/System/Volumes/Data/../Data/Volumes/my_mount    -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc nfs://192.168.1.1:/exports/my_share
```

And re-run the automounter:

```
$ sudo automount -cv
...
automount: /Volumes/my_mount: mounted
```

..... there you go! Technically `/../Volumes` is still `/Volumes`, but the automounter does not see things that way ;)

This configuration persists the mount across restarts, and creates the mountpoint automatically.

**Source github** : https://gist.github.com/L422Y/8697518

Comment: Actually, I am not trying to use /Volumes. I find it rather annoying that Apple has decided that no names should be valid for my filesystem root beyond the standard ones. The line I add is as follows:
/qnap auto_qnap
I of course have the mappings for what should be in /qnap in the auto_qnap file. Whenever MacOS does an OS update, it throws away my line, and often doesn't even make a save file for it in the relocated files (not that I would bother with the save file if they were consistently making one).

Comment: Not an answer to "stop updates overwriting the file".